# how do kedro catalog properties get passed to Datasets when pipeline is executed

Tags: python, kedro

I'm trying to create two custom kedro DataSets and I'm not quite sure how to configure the `__init__` methods.
The first DataSet is simple, its a readonly, fetch rss items from a static URL.
catalog entry:

```
rss_feed_extract:
  type: kedro_workbench.extras.datasets.RSSDataSet.RSSFeedExtract
  url: https://api.msrc.microsoft.com/update-guide/rss
```

class definition

```
class RSSFeedExtract(AbstractDataSet):
    def __init__(self, url: str):
        self._url = url <- how/when does kedro pass this from the catalog entry?
    def _save():
        DataSetError
    def _load():
        dictionary=feedparser(self._url)
        #some minor processing
        return {dictionary}
```

the function mapped to the node definition

```
def extract_rss_feed() -> Dict[str, Any]:
    raw_rss_feed = RSSFeedExtract() <- do I manually pass the catalog property here or does kedro?
    raw_rss_feed.load() <- do I manually call the load method or does the pipeline?
    
    return {'key_1':'value_1', 'key_2': 'value_2'}
```

the node definition in the pipeline

```
node(
            func=extract_rss_feed,
                inputs=None, <- not sure if I'm supposed to pass the dataset name here or not
                outputs='rss_feed_for_transforming',
                name="extract_rss_feed",
        ),
```

when I try to run the above, I get the following error:
`TypeError: RSSFeedExtract.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'`
So I just need some help understanding how to pass catalog properties into the DataSet classes

I tried to create an instance of the built-in APIDataset and I got that working but I didn't need to pass the url property to the function/node calling it, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. My thinking was that the node doesn't take an input because it is fetching data so inputs=None. But maybe I'm supposed to set inputs='rss_feed_extract'? I'm not clear.

What I want is to create a class that fetches rss items and returns a dictionary of the items and I want the node that references it to output an in-memory DataSet of the dictionary that I can pass into the next node to filter and transform the feed items.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're supposed to pass the dataset name as `input` to the node and also to make the node function (in your case `extract_rss_feed` not use the dataset class directly.

Kedro first instantiates the `*Dataset` class with the appropriate arguments from the YAML file, in your case `url`, and then passes the return value of `.load()` to the node function.

As a result, your node functions never see `*Dataset` objects, only primitive types (or whatever you return from `_load`). For example, nodes matched to a `pandas.CSVDataSet` would not see a `CSVDataSet`, but a `pd.DataFrame`.

Your code would look like this:

```py
# pipeline.py

...
    node(
        func=extract_rss_feed,
        inputs='rss_feed_extract',
        outputs='rss_feed_for_transforming',
        name="extract_rss_feed",
    ),


# nodes.py

def extract_rss_feed(feed: Dict) -> Dict:
    return {"key1": feed["key1"], "key2": feed["key2"]}
```

Comment: thank you kindly. that helped get me going!

Comment: glad to know @user3109374! Consider upvoting the answer too :)

Comment: I tried but I'm not allowed yet, sorry.